# consulta basica de debug en una app laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Ayer me pasaron una tarea en la oficina, en la cual debo realizar algunas mantenciones a una aplicación hecha en laravel con BD Oracle 11Gr2

Nunca antes he programado con laravel, y me encuentro en la necesidad de debugear algunos datos que vienen desde la Base de datos

Hasta el momento he podido ver valores de variables usando la sentencia `var_dump($value);`

pero ahora estoy necesitando desplegar el  contenido de un `select`, y al momento de hacer el `var_dump` de la variable que trae el `select`, me reclama con un mensaje de error
este es el "`query`" que se genera en el `controller`

```
    $unidad_actual = \DB::select('select ' .
        '  un.nivel ' .
        '  , un.id ' .
        '  , un.nombre ' .
        'from usuarios us ' .
        'inner join unidades un ' .
        'on un.id = us.unidades_id ' .
        'where us.id = ?', [Auth::user()->id])[0];
```

El error aparece cuando se hace un var_dum de la siguiente manera

```
foreach($unidad_actual as $item){ 
    var_dump($unidad_actual->$item->id;
}
```

me entrega el error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

me cerciore que el `select` trae registros (porque puse un `var_dump("hola")`; que aparece 3 veces en pantalla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que al usar el Query Builder no estás cargando una colección de modelos de Eloquent y por ese motivo no están disponibles las relaciones como propiedades dinámicas, como sí lo hace Eloquent.

Si deseas poder cargar las relaciones de dicha forma (como propiedades dinámicas), idealmente deberás usar Eloquent, partiendo de algún modelo.

Según veo, tu consulta está relacionada con los usuarios, así que ese sería tu modelo de partida para la consulta:

```
$unidad_actual = Usuario::find(Auth::user()->id);
```

Esto es un ejemplo muy básico, ten en cuenta que deberás tener tu modelo `Usuario.php` creado y relacionado correctamente con lo que sea que llames «item».

---

En cuanto al uso que planteas de `var_dump()`, Laravel tiene un helper más potente que dicha función, es `dump()`, revisa su [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-dump).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. encontre en la documentacion que indicaste la funcion print_r que me sirve para ver directamente el resultado de un select.

Answer (score 2):

Estás haciendo mal el var_dump, deberías hacerlo de esta forma para que obtengas algún resultado

```php
foreach($unidad_actual as $item){ 
    var_dump($item->id);
}
```

Comment: hola, gracias por el comentario, la verdad es que lo tenia como indicas,. Al escribir el post, me equivoque al copiar el codigo. Gracias de todas formas

Answer (score -1):

El var_dump que haces esta malo, hace referencia a la colección que estas intentando recorrer y no al elemento que se encuentra dentro del ciclo Foreach.

Debe ser de la siguiente manera.

```
foreach($unidad_actual as $item){ 
var_dump($item) }
```

Comment: ¿Esto que tiene de distinto a la respuesta de Alfredo?

Comment: hola, gracias por el comentario, la verdad es que lo tenia como indicas,. Al escribir el post, me equivoque al copiar el codigo. Gracias de todas formas